# commit and push filetype but never fetch it

Tags: git

Is there a way where I can commit and push a filetype but never pull it from other the repo?

The filetype needs to be a compilation of the incoming *un*compiled files and my commits, so when I pull the compiled files, the auto compiler will compile immediately and cause a merging error. This way I can compile once I have all the changes manually compile before pushing

I have tried turning off the auto-compiler temporarily but every so often someone forgets to and end up wasting time fixing it.

edit: So we are working with .scss and codekit to autocompile. If we do not compile before pushing, the server will have outdated .css files

Comment: filetype? auto-compiler?

Comment: so basically you always wanna keep your version of the file?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella yes, I didn't think of it like that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `theFile` is the file you wanna prevent from being merged when you pull the repo, you can execute

```
echo 'theFile merge=ours' > .gitattributes
git add .gitattributes
git commit -m "Added .gitattributes for preventing theFile to be merged"
```

After doing this, any subsequent `git pull` will leave `theFile` unchanged and your local version will always be used.

An alternative to create and add a `.gitattributes` file is to add the line

```
theFile merge-ours
```

to the `.git/info/attributes` file. If you do so, this behavior will happen only locally, whereas if you commit and push the `.gitattributes` file this will happen in every repo.

Comment: Do I also have to specify the path of the file?

Comment: if its in subdirectory yes, you do. Say your file is in a directory called `foo`, then you'll write `foo/theFile`. Also you can specify whole directories simply writing `foo/`